# In the new Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server project type, what is the .dbproj.schemaview file for?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

And should I add it to the source code repository?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is for state persistence for Schema View.
The state of this view is saved locally, there is no need to add it to source code.

The SQL Server project type has a special *Schema View* window and an extra *Data* menu item.

Also the Solution Explorer gets two extra buttons: *Database Schema View* and *Reanalyze Project*.

When the Schema View is open, 4 menu items under *Data|Schema View* are activated with the same functionality as 4 of the buttons in the Schema View window (a rather strange button in the Schema View window is the Solution Explorer button to return to the Solution Explorer..)

Note e.g. the *External elements* and *Built in elements* menu items in the Schema View window.
When you select *Built in elements* schema's of built-in db-roles become visible (e.g. db_owner).
When you select *External elements* schema's defined in different projects may become visible.

Such settings are saved in the schemaview file.