# AnkhSvn ignoring database project files question

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn, database-project

There are a number of files in my database project that AnkhSvn isn't committing to the repository.  To clean things up using Tortoise, can I safely add them all to the ignore list?

```
Projectname.dbmdl
Projectname.dbproj.schemaview
Projectname.dbproj.user
Sql\debug\*
Sql\release\*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, add those to the ignore list. AnkhSVN doesn't need that, because Visual Studio tells Ankh what files should be source controlled (and it ignores the rest).

They are all user files and/or generated. See linked questions for more info about [`.dbproj.schemaview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937160/in-the-new-visual-studio-2010-sql-server-project-type-what-is-the-dbproj-schema) and [`.dbmdl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634649/what-is-the-function-of-the-dbmdl-file-in-vs-database-project) files. The rest speaks for itself.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the sql\* folders are for?